# Wifi extender won't connect to home router, but can connect to a different access point

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

When I connect my Wi-Fi extender (D-Link DR505) to the main router, I get no internet access. However, when I connect the extender to an access point in another room which is connected to the same router via an Ethernet cable, all works fine. I have tried several different settings, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.
Any ideas anyone? Thanks.

Comment: When I connect my Wi-Fi extender (D-Link DR505) to the main router, I get no internet access  ...   Connect LAN port to LAN port and set up so there is only one DHCP server on your network.

Comment: It's connected via wifi.

Comment: I thought it could be because the main router and the D-Link extender both have the both have the same IP address, 192.168.0.1 whereas the second access point has a different IP address. So I changed the IP address on the extender, after which it stopped working altogether and I had to reset it. Am I on the right track, or am I barking up the wrong tree?